# Python equivalent of db.getCollectionInfos

Tags: python, mongodb, validation, pymongo

I am trying to find a way to list all of the validation rules of a mongodb collection and I would like to do it with python

In the mongo shell the command is this:

```
db.getCollectionInfos()
```

However I have not been able to identify an equivalent command in pymongo

```
db.foo.collection_infos()
db.foo.getCollectionInfos()
```

both fail with (or with something similar):

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'get_collection_infos' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Then I tried putting essentially random commands into the interpreter

```
db.command({"foo": "getCollectionInfos"})
```

Unsurprisingly that also didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command wrapped by the `getCollectionInfos` mongo shell command is [`listCollections` administrative command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/#dbcmd.listCollections).

[Administrative commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/nav-administration/) are available to run against the database. However, some [mongo shell methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/) share similar names with administrative commands (*.e.g.* *cloneConnection*, *currentOp*, *dropDatabase*, and so on). It is easy to think that other mongo shell methods are administrative command but they aren't.

**Using the listCollections command** e.g.

```
# Return information for all collections in the database.
db.command('listCollections')

# Return information for collection `a`
db.command({'listCollections': 1, 'filter': {'name': 'a'}})
```